# Insert plotly generated interactive chart to bitbucket markdown or micorsoft sharepoint

Tags: html, sharepoint, plotly, bitbucket

I am creating an interactive treemap using plotly to show interactive hierarchy of my system. This can be exported to a html file which can be opened locally via desktop browser.

I now want to host a wikipage of my system via bitbucket markdown pages. I attempt to insert the html file into the markdown page as the following

```
[Overrall Architecture](./files/plotly.html)
```

When I click the link, it shows the html raw text instead of the interactive html content. It seems bitbucket stops to support the html hosting [Link](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-3035)

Then I try to upload this to company sharepoint and put sharepoint link from markdown, attempting to open it like a normal webpage.

```
[Overrall Architecture](https:sharepoint.../plotly.html)
```

However, this opens a blank webpage without any content inside it, seems sharepoint also don't provide full support to html hosting.

Any suggestion on how should I proceed?